# mysql. Select column as column1 where... union all select column as column2 where... See only column1 (not column2)

Tags: mysql

Here placed example http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/af548/2

Have table

```
NumberRenamed | TopicName | LanguageId    

1               Topic en      1
2               Topic es      2
3               Topic es1     2
```

Query

```
SELECT `TopicName` AS `TopicName1` FROM `topics` WHERE `LanguageId` = 1

UNION ALL

SELECT `TopicName` AS `TopicName2` FROM `topics` WHERE `LanguageId` = 2

;
```

Expect to get array, like

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [TopicName1] => Topic en
    )
[1] => Array
    (
        [TopicName2] => Topic es
    )
[2] => Array
    (
        [TopicName2] => Topic es1
    )

)
```

But see

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [TopicName1] => Topic en
    )
[1] => Array
    (
        [TopicName1] => Topic es
    )
[2] => Array
    (
        [TopicName1] => Topic es1
    )

)
```

See only `[TopicName1]` (no `[TopicName2]`)

What is wrong with my query (what need to correct)?

Comment: union takes the field names from the first select statement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try with [SQL CASE Expression](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/39103/A-Simple-Use-of-SQL-CASE-Expression)

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ae5a14/5)

```
SELECT CASE `LanguageId` 
     WHEN '1' THEN 'TopicName1'
     WHEN '2' THEN 'TopicName2'
     END AS Topic,
    `TopicName`
 FROM Topics;
```

Get output as

```
|      Topic | TopicName |
|------------|-----------|
| TopicName1 |  Topic en |
| TopicName2 |  Topic es |
| TopicName2 | Topic es1 |
```

Answer (score 1):

if you use `UNION` the column names will only  taken from the first `select´ statement. There is nothing wrong with your query.

Comment: What query must use to have column names also from second `select` statement?